# How can I use .endReceivingRemoteControlEvents to end remote command center?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this

```
// Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        
        
        // Add handler for Play Command
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.isReadyToPlay, let player = self.audioPlayer, player.timeControlStatus != .playing  {
                self.playCC()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
        
        // Add handler for Pause Command
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.isReadyToPlay, let player = self.audioPlayer, player.timeControlStatus == .playing  {
                self.pauseCC()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }
```

When the view disappears, I want to remove the audio playing from the command center. How can I do that? I'm told endReceivingRemoteControlEvents is function I want to use, but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to set player to nil

```
self.player = nil
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [:]
UIApplication.shared.endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Comment: Please don't post the same answer at mutliple questions. If you think that they duplicate each other, choose one and flag the others as duplicates